# Какую сложность выбрать?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Есть алгоритм, который находит уникальный элемент в списке:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def find_uniq_1(arr):
    a, b = set(arr) # O(len(arr))
    return a if arr.count(a) == 1 else b # O(n)

print(find_uniq_1([ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1 ]))
```

Он состоит всего из двух строк кода. Сложность каждой строки я определил, но затрудняюсь выбрать из них ту, которая больше влияет на итоговую сложность алгоритма. Помогите пожалуйста.

Я пробовал увеличивать количество аргументов и при измерять время исполнения. В результате вижу, что график растёт почти линейно. То есть O(n) скорее всего это то, что мне нужно. Но я не понимаю почему O(n) нужно было предпочесть O(len(arr)).

Есть на этот счёт какие-нибудь правила?

Comment: подумайте, что такое здесь `n`

Comment: Кстати, почему set() возвращает кортеж?

Comment: @MBo насколько я вижу, в моём коде нет кортежа. Я просто элементы множества присваиваю обычным переменным... Или я не правильно вопрос понял?

Comment: @MBo, видимо, это как-то связано с тем, что во входном списке только единицы и двойки. Если есть гарантия, что что в списке всегда будет последовательность из двух уникальных элементов - то это будет работать. Но выглядит действительно как-то очень ненадёжно.

Comment: @Александр я специально сделал такие допущения. Иначе разные проверки только отвлекали бы внимание

Comment: @cyklop77, MBo подразумевал, что множественное присваивание подразумевает неявное приведение к кортежу с его последующей распаковкой. Подводный камень здесь в том, что ваша запись подразумевает, что переменных всегда будет получаться ровно две. Однако set вообще не даёт никаких гарантий по числу элементов - он может вернуть и больше, и меньше. Если уверены, что там всегда будет только два значения - то, в принципе, ваш вариант нормальный, просто со стороны выглядит странно.

Comment: Я бы сказал, что данный алгоритм находит уникальный элемент в списке из 2-х элементов, один из которых обязательно встречается ровно 1 раз. Что, на мой взгляд, *совершенно* не соответствует задаче "найти уникальный элемент в списке".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Линейная сложность - это когда количество вычислительных итераций находится в линейной зависимости от КОЛИЧЕСТВА ЭЛЕМЕНТОВ ВО ВХОДНЫХ ДАННЫХ.

Длинна входного массива - это и есть количество элементов на входе.

То есть ваше `O(len(arr))` - это просто нестандартный способ записи для `O(n)`.